Download IMF data
I am trying to download data with imf.data package. Below you can see my code with example of single country.
library(imf.data)
library(tidyverse)
DOT <- load_datasets("DOT")

DOT$get_series(freq = "M",
               ref_area ="GB", #<-----This line here 
               indicator = "TMG_CIF_USD",
               counterpart_area = c("B0","W00"),
               start_period = "2022-01-01",
               end_period = "2022-12-31")

So far, so good. This code works perfectly when I work with one or several groups of countries. However, a problem arises when I want to download all countries available in the code for additional calculations. For this purpose, this line needs to be set, but I don't know how to set it.
 ref_area ="GB" 

List of the countries inside in the code is avilalbe on the following command:
DOT$dimensions$ref_area

Can anybody help me how I can download data for each country in the dataset ?

DOT$dimensions$ref_area$Value contains all possible ref_area codes, i.e. dropping the description column.
So, to get the first 5, i.e. "AF"  "F19" "AL"  "DZ"  "AS":
library(imf.data)

DOT <- load_datasets("DOT")

DOT$get_series(
  freq = "M",
  ref_area = DOT$dimensions$ref_area$Value[1:5],
  indicator = "TMG_CIF_USD",
  counterpart_area = c("B0", "W00"),
  start_period = "2022-01-01",
  end_period = "2022-12-31"
)
#>    TIME_PERIOD M.AL.TMG_CIF_USD.B0 M.DZ.TMG_CIF_USD.W00 M.AF.TMG_CIF_USD.W00
#> 1      2022-01          268.800991          3214.067303           381.086758
#> 2      2022-02          350.579968           3200.83206           396.921518
#> 3      2022-03          393.525928          3787.143548           310.286966
#> 4      2022-04          368.922968          3133.389179           262.121963
#> 5      2022-05          372.959459          3575.477391           430.224589
#> 6      2022-06          366.534067          3789.034029           348.796569
#> 7      2022-07          389.159249          3139.037467           463.802374
#> 8      2022-08          326.246664          3366.147213           224.031354
#> 9      2022-09           374.71781          3168.200432           321.414107
#> 10     2022-10          367.432885          3325.067663           319.096516
#> 11     2022-11          360.972688          3503.927615           317.945892
#> 12     2022-12          394.164153          3702.748205           301.800463
#>    M.DZ.TMG_CIF_USD.B0 M.AF.TMG_CIF_USD.B0 M.AL.TMG_CIF_USD.W00
#> 1          1039.395754           13.509881           512.625048
#> 2          1113.544658           14.071237            641.90928
#> 3          1313.487929           10.999962           749.514065
#> 4          1032.409471            9.292467           697.124131
#> 5          1255.905059           15.251862            699.23203
#> 6          1215.547344           12.365162           716.644465
#> 7            1007.2708           16.442226           708.349773
#> 8          1229.656053            7.942119           689.077306
#> 9          1073.895526           11.394428           744.955435
#> 10         1163.138001           11.312267           698.386028
#> 11         1161.242924           11.271478           671.673005
#> 12         1193.062415           10.699108           871.429803
#>    M.AS.TMG_CIF_USD.W00 M.AS.TMG_CIF_USD.B0
#> 1             12.175389            0.379057
#> 2              8.801094            0.087784
#> 3              15.72431            0.321824
#> 4             13.352435             0.03355
#> 5              8.397788             5.5E-05
#> 6             20.881022            0.489287
#> 7             27.141634            0.184382
#> 8             17.810841            0.105797
#> 9             17.975746            0.256393
#> 10            41.386464            0.013516
#> 11            23.901932            0.268387
#> 12             11.39569            0.233004

Created on 2024-05-08 with reprex v2.1.0

This works only partially. Please put this line for all countries, and you will see the problem again ref_area = DOT$dimensions$ref_area$Value,

There are some "bad" country codes that return no data. Using DOT$dimensions$ref_area$Value[c(1:21, 23:56, 58:60)] works by skipping 22 and 57. You could gradually increase the ranges and skip any "bad" ones. To see the skipped ones: DOT$dimensions$ref_area[c(22, 57),]

Another option is to create a loop and iterate one at a time (rather than all at once) auto-skipping the ones that return NULL.
